# How to get last rows with group by in Laravel eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel

I want to find the last rows with `groupBy` in Laravel. I've table like below:

```
id name ad_id
1  a    1
2  b    2
3  a    2
4  c    1
```

I want the result to be grouped by `ad_id` like below:

```
id name ad_id
3  a    2
4  c    1
```

My current query:

```
MyTable::groupBy('ad_id')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

which returns the first two rows.
So, what should be my eloquent query?

Comment: What happened to the `b` name record?  What is the logic behind this output?

Comment: I do not need each `name`. I just need the last `name` in each `ad_id`.

Comment: Please post your current Laravel/Eloquent code.

Comment: I've updated my question with current query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot just use the `group by` and `order by` to select the max id in Mysql.
It will alway return the min `id`.

Try to use `subquery` and `group by` `MAX()` like this:

```php
MyTable::whereIn('id', function($query) {
   $query->from('my_tables')->groupBy('ad_id')->selectRaw('MAX(id)');
})->get();
```

Comment: My table has no id with auto incrementing so I substitue id with created_at and it works the same way. thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the raw MySQL query you would likley use here:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.ad_id
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ad_id, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY ad_id
) t2
    ON t1.ad_id = t2.ad_id AND
       t1.id = t2.max_id;
```

Here is the Laravel code for the above query:

```
MyTable::from('yourTable AS t1')
    ->select('t1.id', 't1.name', 't1.ad_id')
    ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT ad_id, MAX(id) AS max_id
                     FROM yourTable
                     GROUP BY ad_id)
           t2'), 
    function($join)
    {
       $join->on('t1.ad_id', '=', 't2.ad_id');
       $join->on('t1.id', '=', 't2.max_id');
    })
    ->orderBy('t1.id')
    ->get();
```